# How to keep <font> or <style> tags from getting in WYSIWYG editor with ckeditor?

Tags: wysiwyg

Seems simple, but I haven't been able to find any way to do it.

To be clear, I want ALL other tags for this text format, just not font or style tags.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use a text filter (format) that allows all tags you want and doesn't allow font and style tags. I also recommend removing toolbar buttons that add these tags, such as font, font color, font size etc. You could add custom styles that add CSS selectors rather than inline style tags.

Comment: I suppose I could do that, but to me it seems like such a common problem - people copy paste from Word and even using the Paste from Word box, line-height and other styles get used - that I've been hoping for a more simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a long thread discussing this problem here: http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9998 - CKEditor is working on a fix for it even though it appears to be a browser bug.

A temporary workaround you might try is here: http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor/ckeditor-4.01-inserting-span-elements-everywhere-with-a-line-height-of-1.6em

Nutshell: search for and remove/edit the following line from the CKEditor CSS: .cke_editable { font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.6em; }

I have not fully tested it, but so far it appears to be working.